# How can I get DispatchQueue() code to cleanup on application exit

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I have a process running in a DispatchQueue which creates a temporary file. The file is deleted in a defer block so the clean up occurs regardless of whether an error is thrown or I just return from `process()` normally. See code below

```
func process() throws {
    let file = createTemporaryFile()
    defer {
        deleteTemporaryFile(file)
    }
    try callCodeThatMightThrowErrors()
} 

dispatchQueue.async {
    do {
        try process()
    } catch {
        dealWithError()
    }
}
```

Now this all works fine until I quit my application. If I have a DispatchQueue currently in the middle of the `process()` function the defer block is not run and the file is not deleted and I leave a temporary file in the system. Is there any way I can get this defer block to be called? I would rather not have to store a global array of temporary files that need to be deleted at application exit.

Comment: Yeah I meant errors. Edited the question to indicate that. The function callCodeThatMightThrowErrors() can last quite a long period of time. So the executing finite length tasks won't work in this case. It's useful to know about though. Although I've seen that is for iOS and not macOS.

Comment: After writing this question I’ve thought about this a lot and I’ve had to rethink how I should deal with processes still running when I quit and realised I need to terminate these in as tidy a way as possible. So this question is not really valid anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either:

- a) prevent your app from terminating while your process is running, OR
- b) know when termination is happening and cancel your process

Either way, `NSApplicationDelegate` has a method (`applicationShouldTerminate`) to ask you if it can terminate. While your process is running, you should return `NSTerminateLater`, and then when the process is done, call `replyToApplicationShouldTerminate`.

You should also make sure that sudden termination is disabled while your process is running so that you actually get the termination delgation. See `ProcessInfo` disableSuddenTermination`

Comment: Ive had to rethink how I deal with still running processes when quitting. Your answer covers the start of where I was going.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to clean up on app exit though? If you are sure that no temporary file can exist on app start then add your cleanup code there. That way no matter how a user or the OS terminated the app, your cleanup code would run. Of course, if the process is not terminated you can clean the temp files where you do it now.